# How to create forms in Microsoft Sharepoint?

Tags: forms, sharepoint

Hi I want to create form on my site, which is run using Micrsoft Sharepoint.

Answer (score 3):

there are multiple ways to create/use forms in SharePoint. You can do this by

- implementing a web part
- designing/implementing an aspx page
- using InfoPath

To decide which option is the right one for you depends on the problem you want so solve or the goal you want do archive. Perhaps some more details would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

That's a very broad question.  As Flo writes, there are many ways to do this, and there is no one best choice.  In addition to the three ways he lists, I'll add one more:

- Use the Survey list type to allow users to create simple forms without customization and development.  It's meant for surveys, but combined with a mail alert it works well for simple forms.

Of course any custom list can be used in this way.